# Changing font colour of StyledTextCtrl

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am trying to change the default font colour of the following StyledTextCtrl,
I've been testing this for awhile and changing the hex code values however I can't seem to get it to change colour. (I want it to be purple). The current default colour is Black.

When I add

```
self.StyleSetForeground(wx.stc.STC_STYLE_DEFAULT,wx.Colour(230, 230, 250))
```

It changes the colour of the line number. (On the side of the StyledTextCtrl, it shows the line you are on).

Does anyone know a solution, or maybe whats causing the confliction?

Comment: You might want to trim your code and only show us the relevant sections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.StyleSetForeground(wx.stc.STC_STYLE_DEFAULT,wx.Colour(230, 230, 250))` will only change the colour of **the default style**.

Your code uses many different styles, each with their own colour specified. Notice the "fore" argument in the following code:

```
self.StyleSetSpec(stc.STC_P_COMMENTLINE,
    "fore:#007F00,face:%(other)s,size:%(size)d" % faces)
```

It seems like your line numbers are using the default style and all the other text is using their own style. I don't understand where the styles are being set so I can't explain is why the line numbers don't use `wx.stc.STC_STYLE_LINENUMBER`.

So, either remove the `self.StlyeSetSpec()` calls or include your `self.StyleSetForeground()` call at the end of the initializer (and don't forget to call `self.StyleClearAll()` to reset all the text to the default style).