# wx Python - colour coding - StyledTextctrl

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

## My Problem:

Hi! i have been googling for 2 days right now, and i have not found an answer 
yet :( what am i trying to do is when i type a keyword(e.g "True" and "False") that word would turn red

i am currently imported this module:

```
import wx
import wx.stc
import os, sys
```

## I have tried:

i have tried code from here: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873036/changing-font-colour-of-styledtextctrl)
but that does not do "some" keyword but "all" word next to it

[Screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7b3SY.png)

Any Help Would Be Very Appreciated

Comment: can you show more code? I.e. how did you create Scintilla object and set the lexer?

Comment: You have to include "True" and "False" in the keyword list (you can have more than 1) and then assign a color to that particular list. Needless to say if you set the lexer to Python, it will save you from quite bit of work as well.

Comment: Do I need to install scintilla?

Comment: No, you dont need to. `wxStyledTextCtrl` should do the job. http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/classwx_styled_text_ctrl.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First derive a class which is a subclass of `wxStyledTextCtrl`

```
class Script:public wxStyledTextCtrl
```

*The following code is for **Lua***, but the same logic is applicable to any language. So you will need to modify it for Python and add the code to your constructor.

```
SetLexer(wxSTC_LEX_LUA); //Dont forget to set the lexer to Python
m_LuaKeywords =_T("and break do else elseif end false for function if in local nil not or repeat return then true until while pairs ipairs");     
SetWordChars(wxT("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMONPQRSTUVWXYZ._") );
SetKeyWords(0,m_LuaKeywords);
SetFont(font);

StyleSetForeground(0,  wxColour(128, 128, 128)); // White space
StyleSetForeground(wxSTC_LUA_COMMENT,  wxColour(0,   127, 0));   // Block Comment
font.SetPointSize(10); font.Italic();
StyleSetFont(wxSTC_LUA_COMMENT, font);
StyleSetUnderline(wxSTC_LUA_COMMENT, false);

StyleSetForeground(wxSTC_LUA_COMMENTLINE, wxColour(0,   127, 0));   //Line Comment
StyleSetFont(wxSTC_LUA_COMMENTLINE,font);    //doc. Comment
StyleSetUnderline(wxSTC_LUA_COMMENTLINE, false);

font.SetPointSize(11);font.SetStyle(wxFONTSTYLE_NORMAL);
StyleSetForeground(wxSTC_LUA_NUMBER, wxColour(127, 127, 127)); // Number
StyleSetFont(wxSTC_LUA_NUMBER, font);

StyleSetForeground(wxSTC_LUA_STRING, wxColour(0,   0,   127)); // Double quoted string
StyleSetBold(wxSTC_LUA_STRING,  true);
StyleSetUnderline(wxSTC_LUA_STRING, false);
```

If you look at `wx/stc/stc.h`, you will see that the states for Python are as follows:

```
/// Lexical states for SCLEX_PYTHON
#define wxSTC_P_DEFAULT 0
#define wxSTC_P_COMMENTLINE 1
#define wxSTC_P_NUMBER 2
#define wxSTC_P_STRING 3
#define wxSTC_P_CHARACTER 4
#define wxSTC_P_WORD 5
#define wxSTC_P_TRIPLE 6
#define wxSTC_P_TRIPLEDOUBLE 7
#define wxSTC_P_CLASSNAME 8
#define wxSTC_P_DEFNAME 9
#define wxSTC_P_OPERATOR 10
#define wxSTC_P_IDENTIFIER 11
#define wxSTC_P_COMMENTBLOCK 12
#define wxSTC_P_STRINGEOL 13
#define wxSTC_P_WORD2 14
#define wxSTC_P_DECORATOR 15
```

Comment: Ok Thanks for the help everybody! I'll try what i got